# NSolve returns empty set instead of expected solutions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Consider the list `tab` (located at http://pastebin.com/504T3PzS due to its size) containing four numeric expressions with analytic unknowns `x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]`. From previous considerations I expect to find `120` different sets of solutions for the unknowns if I try

```
NSolve[tab == {0, 0, 0, 0}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]},WorkingPrecision->250]
```

However, after a few seconds the function just returns

> `{}`

which seems to suggest that no solutions exist. However, I am certain that the previously mentioned solutions must exist. Is there anything I can do to tweak the routine and find the solutions? Thanks for any suggestion!

EDIT:

One can do a variable transform and make the expected solution values close to 1. Here is the new `tab` list after the transformation: http://pastebin.com/rDjwW0Sc

Comment: Using replace lists, it seems they go asymptotically to 0.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow, what do you mean by "replace lists"? Also, I do expect several of the solutions to contain numbers on the order between `10^-10` and `10^-20`, if that is what you mean by "asymptotically going to zero"?

Comment: Well, that's relevant to know, if it's not close to 1, you need to prime the functions.

Comment: What does it mean to "prime the functions"? I did a variable transform and made the expected solutions close to 1, here the new `tab` list: http://pastebin.com/rDjwW0Sc

Comment: That's one way, another way is to tell the functions the solutions are far from `0th order`.

Comment: Might work better to get rid of denominators and force a method that will tend to not get messed up by machine arithmetic. This might work (it's slow so I'm not sure yet). `NSolve[Numerator[Together[Rationalize[tab, 0]]], 
 Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]`. Could put back the `WorkingPrecision` option if this fails.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `x[1]` etc as variables, I've used gedit replaceall, to `x1` etc.

Both your original solver, and @Daniel Lichtblau's suggestion of:

```
NSolve[Numerator[Together[Rationalize[tab, 0]]],Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]
```

now take a very long time to complete, you can try it, but it might just run forever.

You can acquire single solutions with `FindRoot[]`, priming `FindRoot[]` with different values yields different results, this doesn't yield all results of course but it works.
When the order of the solutions are far from $\mathbb{O}\left(0\right)$, you need to let *Mathematica*.

```
sol = FindRoot[
   tab, {{x1, 10*^-11}, {x2, 10*^-11}, {x3, 10*^-11}, {x4, 10*^-11}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 250]
```

> `{x1 -> 1.7303209360273081166080795511236987754452090493069052033634505\
>   7126341019665141623205741988063321928031129251609110091077373071624678\
>   5444572947144194574712171293799707185828789871142196406530671743061174\
>   628930044958042503703454280813274589075226478500*10^-9, 
>    x2 -> 1.1332092352951277907686266058027803390268941332839920280607743\
>   7262862829319838550577452680581794485876567376745162640489572438855714\
>   7619709810657958627082830466483341412666913953794552647159607503944553\
>   559323222181106263502661033390175140743925665876, 
>    x3 -> 0.3154994024936458362045781748042449530864905254938750817906877\
>   0928188899337611419671939563231136113335760672846229509989065050186679\
>   3388686137788874951706267788483690347401986026078871821498634537218800\
>   6716663681091789285987099802483538292917146873169, 
>    x4 -> 0.0044792362208696398240090605019724426022841404797335376949181\
>   4498777297043633615312806423579219089116715768706140196045965937215183\
>   3173357503131755672492703813889252331251789568651936153206383672569894\
>   518975631114820988349448877727395437621001311879008}`

```
tab /. sol
```

> `{0.*10^-256, 0.*10^-256, 0.*10^-256, 0.*10^-256}`

Comment: Hmm, `10^-256` is too small, no such solution is expected.

Comment: @That's not the solution, that's to check the solution.

Comment: Oh, I see! Yes, this seems to be one of the solutions then. But I need to find a total of `120` solutions. Is it possible to retrieve all of them systematically?

Comment: @Kagaratsch re-running `NSolve[]` with new parameter, not immediately returning `{}`, maybe because I use `x1..` instead of `x[1]`, I'm not sure that notation works. Might take a few minutes to complete.